# SQL to find time difference between two values in a group

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, date-arithmetic

I have an sql table like the one shown below.

```
+---------------------+--------+-------+
|        time         | item   | state |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
| 2019-07-19 1:50:00 | a      |   st1 |
| 2019-07-19 2:51:00 | a      |   st2 |
| 2019-07-19 2:55:00 | b      |   st1 |
| 2019-07-19 2:59:00 | b      |   st2 |
| 2019-07-19 4:30:00 | a      |   st3 |
+---------------------+--------+-------+
```

I need to figure out how much time it took for item to change state from st1 to st2 and so on..

The final output table should look something like this.

```
+--------+------------+---------------+
| item   | st1_to_st2 |   st2_to_st3  | and so on
+--------+------------+---------------+
| a      |   x seconds| w-seconds     |
| b      |   y-seconds| z-seconds     |
+--------+------------+---------------+
```

Can you please help me with the sql.

Comment: Creating a result row with undefined number of columns is possible with big expenses. But normally this makes no sense at all. Perhaps you should rethink your concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed list of states, you can use window functions and aggregation:

```
select item,
    sum(case when lag_state = 'st1' and state = 'st2' then timestampdiff(second, lag_time, time)) as st1_to_st2,
    sum(case when lag_state = 'st2' and state = 'st3' then timestampdiff(second, lag_time, time)) as st2_to_st3
from (
    select t.*,
        lag(time)  over(partition by item order by state) lag_time,
        lag(state) over(partition by item order by state) lag_state
    from mytable t
) t
group by item
```

If you want something more generic - ie that does not harcode the states - I would recommend putting the values in rows rather than in columns:

```
select item, lag_state, state, 
    sum(timestampdiff(second, lag_time, time)) as sum_diff
from (
    select t.*,
        lag(time)  over(partition by item order by state) lag_time,
        lag(state) over(partition by item order by state) lag_state
    from mytable t
) t
group by item, lag_state, state
```